# Code printing with support for TrueType, code ligatures, UTF-8, command line

Tags: printing

I'm searching for a tool that can pretty-print code on paper. My requirements are:

- TrueType support
- Supports C/C++
- Coloured output
- Command-line interface (scriptable)
- Runs on Linux
- Supports UTF-8
- Output to printer-ready PS or PDF (A4 format)

Nice to have but not essential:

- Code font ligatures (f.ex. Fira Code)

I'm aware of `a2ps` and `enscript`. Neither supports TrueType or UTF-8. Their code font is Courier, which I dislike. Eclipse prints the way I like, but can't be controlled from the command line.

Comment: You can install extensions to Eclipse and VS Code so they're in a sense "scriptable"